# Move mouse with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do simple mouse move with javascript but I am unable to do it and dont know what is wrong.

```
function doMove(){
    let element = document.getElementById('root');

    let eventMouseDown = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
        clientX: window.innerWidth/2,
        clientY: window.innerHeight/2
    });
    let eventMouseMove = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
        clientX: (window.innerWidth/2)+50,
        clientY: window.innerHeight/2
    });
    let eventMouseUp = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {
        clientX: (window.innerWidth/2)+50,
        clientY: window.innerHeight/2
    });

    element.dispatchEvent(eventMouseDown);
    element.dispatchEvent(eventMouseMove);
    element.dispatchEvent(eventMouseUp);
}
```

First I put mouse down then move and then realease which should simulate me moving with mouse on map for example. How can I make it work?

Comment: triggering those events won't make the mouse move. You can't move the mouse pointer because there's no api to do it. But you can move where the viewport is looking at the page using `scrollTo` for example. Maybe you could fake a pointer somehow hiding the real one with `cursor: none;`. This is actually a great idea :) you have a div chasing the mouse coordinates (the real one hidden). Then you could move that div with code but you need to invent ways to sync back with real mouse coords when moving it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move mouse using JavaScript in the website. Imagine that you are opening a website and it takes control over your mouse.

Comment: Ou right well I just need to simulate some movement on map not actual cursor but yeah i  understand/,